# How to Connect ESP8266 with ultrasonic sensor and dht11 without breadboard?

Tags: esp8266, sensors, temperature-sensor

[image]I want to connect the sensors in Esp8266 after I code those using arduino uno r3. The problem is that I don't have the idea on connecting those sensors without breadboard. Thank you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84446/discussion-on-question-by-bianca-delos-how-to-connect-esp8266-with-ultrasonic-se).

Comment: Don't keep asking the same question in a slightly different way, please.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use a breadboard, you could solder the wires together of tie them together, so long as none of the wires which aren't supposed to be touching are touching. Or you can also use flex tape! (Don't mind my meme)

Comment: aha okay :) I had edited the question and added image from online based on a breadboard

Answer (score 1):

A diagram of the internal wiring of a breadboard is found at http://www.fiz-ix.com/2016/04/breadboard-wiring-diagram/

Image duplicated here:

[image]

All you need to do is make sure all the same connected points from your breadboard circuit remain connected in the same way on a perfboard or PCB.

There are several ways to make a circuit on perfboard, and [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55236/how-to-make-traces-on-an-universal-pcb) on electronics SE shows some examples of using solder bridges as interconnects, short uninsulated wires, and insulated "wire wrap" wires.

You can also find perfboards with the same connection layout as a breadboard for easy transfer from a breadboard-wired circuit, as shown below:

[image]